# (#100) picture URL is not properly formatted - Graph API Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create post link in a Facebook Page via Graph API. All the parameters are working fine, the only one that it is not is the picture.

I am putting the URL for a picture in my desktop, but it is not working, I am receiving this error: (#100) picture URL is not properly formatted

Anyone have any idea how can I do it? Or if it is possible to upload the picture from your compures in a page post link?

This is the code I am using (i hide some information about my password and the token):

```
    <?php


    session_start();

    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookHttpable.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurl.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookClientException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookPermissionException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookServerException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );



    use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
    use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
    use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookClientException;
    use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\FacebookPermissionException;
    use Facebook\FacebookServerException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
    use Facebook\GraphUser;

    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app name','app password');

    $session = new FacebookSession('token');

    $message = 'Test';
    $link = "http://www.example.com";
    $description = 'Descriptionnn';
    $name = 'Nameeee';
    $caption = 'Captionnnnnnnn';
    $picture = 'file:///C:/Users/VIrgilio/Desktop/Petlove/Facebook%20Ads/Campanhas/Assento/Link/Assento-Novo.png';

        $request = new FacebookRequest(
          $session,
          'POST',
          '/page_id/feed',
          array (
            'message' => $message,
            'link' => $link,
            'description' => $description,
            'published' => 'false',
            'name' => $name,
            'caption' => $caption,
            'picture' => $picture,
          )
        );
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

    ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The picture URL should be something like `https://www.example.com/image.jpg`

Comment: But can I do it from my computer? Because the images that I using to post aren`t in my site.

Comment: Then you need to upload the photo to Facebook. Look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/photos

Comment: Thanks.

I read that documentation, and there it says that I need to upload the photo using "multipart/form-data". I am trying to understand how it works and how to use it, but I failed until now.